# How to achieve a WP_Post object from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am having difficult extracting the post_title of a WP_Post object from within an array, which is within an array of an array.

I have created post types and custom fields so that I can have 'meals' within which are the 'ingredients' themselves.

As per this example the end result should be:

Sausages and Mash

Sausages

Potatoes

This is my code:

```
<?php

// Create our arguments for getting our post
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'meals',
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'nopaging' => true,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args) ;

if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>
          
          <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
          <ul>
          <li>
          
          <?php 
    
          $ingredients = get_field('ingredients', $post);
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r ($ingredients); //output array
          echo "</pre>";
          
          echo "<ul>";
          foreach ( $ingredients['post_title'] as $value => $ingredient ): 
             echo "<li>" . $ingredient . "</li>";
          endforeach;
          echo "</ul>";
          
          ?>

          </li>
          </ul>
          
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php }
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Using print_r above we can see the content of the array contains the necessary ingredients:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ingredient] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Post Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 491
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2020-10-28 17:46:10
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2020-10-28 17:46:10
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Sausages
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => open
                            [ping_status] => open
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => sausages
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2020-10-28 17:46:10
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2020-10-28 17:46:10
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => https://www.website.com/home/ingredients/sausages/
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => ingredients
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                )

            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ingredient] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Post Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 448
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2020-10-28 09:23:52
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2020-10-28 09:23:52
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Potatoes
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => potatoes
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2020-10-28 10:57:21
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2020-10-28 10:57:21
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => https://www.website.com/home/?post_type=ingredients&p=448
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => ingredients
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                )

            [quantity] => 1
        )

)
```

So if the information is there, why isn't my foreach $ingredients as $ingredient not displaying the code?

I really appreciate your help as I have spent all afternoon on this referring to many articles on StackOverflow, on Wordpress site and also many independent developers blogs. I know I am missing something and its due to the fact its a post object within an array or an array and despite playing around with variations on the code I still can't crack it.

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Probably want `get_field('ingredients', $post->ID)` , unless 'ingredients' is a post object in the ACF field?  What are you running through in your foreach loop?  This part is also a little confusing.

Comment: @HowardE - Thank you, your comment helped lead me to finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Howard's comment, I looked more closely at this particular routine and I worked it out. I wasn't delving deep enough into the post object's array and the fix is as simple as adding [0] to the echo:

```
echo "<li>" . $ingredient['ingredient'][0]->post_title . "</li>";
```

And that's it - it works.

Thank you.